# Controllability of stochasic bilinear system in 2-dimension

Tags: lie-algebra, stochastic-processes

I have a question about controllability and I am thankful for any reply.

A linear system $\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$ is controllable iff it satisfies the well-known Kalman rank condition. Here, controllability means that there exists a control sequence that drives a system from any arbitrary initial state $x_0$ to any arbitrary open set (with a non-empty interior) $\mathcal{v}$ in finite time.

If Brownian noise $dW(t)$ with variance $dt$ is added, $dx = dt(Ax + Bu) + dW(t)$, the system should still be controllable if $A,B$ are controllable, right? Since the time to reach $x_f$ from $x_0$ can be made arbitrary short (for the noise-free case) by increasing the magnitude of $u$. Thus, the system can reach an arbitrary small open set containing $x_f$ in finite time.

Consider a stochastic bilinear system in 2D $dx = dt(Ax + Bxu) + KdW$ where the Lie algebra generated by $Ax, Bx$ span $\mathcal{R}^2$ (except at $x = 0$) and $u, dW \in \mathcal{R}$ are scalars. In this case, the noise-free system would be controllable except for some special cases (see U. Piechottcka and P. Frank 1992). If we assume that the noise-free bilinear system is controllable, what can we say for the stochastic case? Also, would it matter if the noise entered as $dx = dt(Ax + Bxu) + K(x)dW$?

**My guess**: Both cases (with and without state-dependence in the noise term) are also controllable with the definition of controllability still being the ability to drive the state arbitrary close to $x_f$ from $x_0$ in finite time. My argument is, there exists an $\epsilon(\delta)$ such that $|x_{nf}(t_f) - x(t_f)| < \delta$ if $\int_{t_0}^{t_f}dW^2(t) dt < \epsilon^2$, where $x_{nf}$ is the noise-free evolution (i.e letting $K = 0$). $x_{nf}$ can be driven exactly to $x_f$ (controllable system) and the probability of $\int_{t_0}^{t_f}dW^2(t) dt < \epsilon$ is non-zero if $\epsilon > 0$. This conclusion holds for any $x_0$. Thus, eventually the state must be arbitrary close to $x_f$ which means that the system is controllable.

Is this argument correct or do you think I am missing something? Also, if you know if there exists any good papers that deal with controllability of stochastic, bilinear systems I would be happy to read them.

Best regards

Christoffer

Comment: I think your question is more likely to get *any* response on the https://mathoverflow.net/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/ forums than here.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: There are probably several flavors of controllability, but my off-the-cuff guess is that the condition you are interested in is something like the following: for every pair $x_0$, $x_f$ in $\Omega$, there exists a number (or time) $T(x_0, x_f)$ such that for almost every noise instance $W(t)$ there exists a 'humane' input $u(t)$ such that the solution to $dx = dt(Ax + B(u)x) + KdW(t)$ with initial condition $x(0) = x_0$ reaches $x_f$ in total time less than $T(x_0, x_f)$.  You could also consider a stronger condition, where $T(x_0, x_f)$ is bounded by some constant $T_{max}$.

Comment: (Your argument would fail the above criteria, because even though there is a finite probability of the noise being arbitrarily small, there is no guarantee that it will be 'small' in finite time, and moreover the noise-free time could diverge with the number of failed attempts.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think you might be correct and it will definitely give me something to think about. But maybe the fact that Brownian motion in 1 and 2 dimensions are recurrent and that the deterministic part is stabilizable would at least prohibit the "noise-free time" to diverge?